# Singularity - Centos7 - Permission

Tags: centos7, singularity-container

i use [singularity](https://singularity.lbl.gov/) on Centos7 system, but i block on incomprehensible like-permission problem.

(It's a centrifuge/recentrifuge container made by myself that perfectly working on Ubuntu system)

## command

```
singularity exec /HOMEPATH/Singularity/centrifuge_recentrifuge.simg centrifuge -x /HOMEPATH/Centrifuge/bacteria-database-centrifuge -1 /HOMEPATH/work_directory/centrifuge_recentrifuge/reads/TTOTO_R1_001.fastq.gz -2 /HOMEPATH/work_directory/centrifuge_recentrifuge/reads/TOTO_R2_001.fastq.gz -S /HOMEPATH/work_directory/centrifuge_recentrifuge/classification_result --report-file /HOMEPATH/work_directory/centrifuge_recentrifuge/classification_summary
```

## error log

```
Error: Could not open alignment output file /HOMEPATH/work_directory/centrifuge_recentrifuge/classification_result
Error: Encountered internal Centrifuge exception (#1)
Command: /usr/local/bin/centrifuge-class --wrapper basic-0 -x /HOMEPATH/Centrifuge/bacteria-database-centrifuge -S /HOMEPATH/work_directory/centrifuge_recentrifuge/classification_result --report-file /HOMEPATH/work_directory/centrifuge_recentrifuge/classification_summary -1 /tmp/229778.inpipe1 -2 /tmp/229778.inpipe2 
(ERR): centrifuge-class exited with value 1
```

It's seeem like singularity can not write the tmp files or write the `classification_result` file or the both :/

## work directory permission

```
ls -Z /HOMEPATH/work_directory/centrifuge_recentrifuge/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 reads

ls -Z /HOMEPATH/work_directory/centrifuge_recentrifuge/reads/
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 TOTO_R1_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 TOTO_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

### EDIT 1 Resolve Permission Problem

```
ls -Z centrifuge_recentrifuge
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 reads

ls -Z centrifuge_recentrifuge/reads/
-rw-r--r--. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 TOTO_R1_001.fastq.gz
-rw-r--r--. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 TOTO_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

And the error is still the same... 
I have make a `sudo chown -R apache:apache /tmp` on the tmp folder but it's does not make effect :/

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -Z /HOMEPATH/work_directory/centrifuge_recentrifuge/
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 reads
```

This says that the only the owner of the `centrifuge_recentrifuge` directory has permission to create items in that directory, and that the owner of the directory is the user `root`.  So, only `root` can create items in that directory.

Presumably you were not running the `singularity` program while logged in as `root` and that's why the program was unable to create a `classification_result` file.  It wouldn't have been able to create a `classification_summary` file either, if it had got as far as trying to do that.

I don't know if you have a special reason for having this directory owned by `root`.  If you do, then the only way the program is going to be able to create these files is if you run it as the `root` user.  Of course it's generally a bad idea to use the `root` account for anything other than system administration.

The usual approach is to have the `HOMEPATH` directory, and everything below it, be owned by the individual (non-`root`) user for whom that particular `HOMEPATH` was created.  In this model, that individual user would be the owner of the `centrifuge_recentrifuge` directory, and therefore if you run the `singularity` program when logged in as that user it will be able to create whatever files it needs there.

To get to that situation from where you are now, to change the ownership of `HOMEPATH` and everything beneath it you can log in as `root` (or use `sudo`) and then run:

```
  chown -R myuser /HOMEPATH
```

where `myuser` is the username of the account that has `HOMEPATH` as its home directory.

That should be enough to let the program run.  However, for completeness you should also change the group ownership of `HOMEPATH` and everything beneath it to match the individual user's group.  To do that, run:

```
  chown -R myuser:mygroup /HOMEPATH
```

where `mygroup` is the group that contains the user `myuser`.  If you don't know what that group name should be, log in as `myuser` and run the `id -ng` command.  It's common to have the group name be the same as the user name, so don't be surprised if the result of that `id` command is the same as `myuser`.  On some systems you can run:

```
  chown -R myuser: /HOMEPATH
```

with just a colon `:` after `myuser` and the command will figure out the group name for you.  If that works on your system then you don't need to do the `id -ng` dance.

Comment: yes you have alright on your post. The problem is a permission problem occur by  `celery`. I will make a post on it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52812152/celery-permission-problem-create-folder